# How do i make a Bitbucket repository available to my client in my absence

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm developing some software for my client who is now asking for some assurance that the code/project will be available in my absence. I have a repository for the project in Bitbucket alongside several other repositories ALL are private including the clients project.

I have setup a User-Group for the client and a an email-address for login. **What is the best way to give my client access to ONLY their repository?** Is it via a **Team, Group or individual-User** account. I would rather they don't even see other repositories other than their own.

Ideally my client would pass the repository ownership over to a new developer should they need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give them access to the repo only.
If you go to `https://bitbucket.org/<YOUR>/<REPO>/admin/access`, then **User and group access** you can add a specific user account (assuming they've signed up on BB).
That way they'll only have access to that repo - and can't view anything else in your team.

Comment: I would have to get them to create an account on BB then, thats the bit i haven't done! i thought i could allow access via a group created for them, now it makes sense; i couldn't see how they could login without a password. Hence the 5-users limit for the free account. Ok got it cheers